# Why doesn't my VB mail merge from Access actually send the email(s)?

Tags: vb.net, email, ms-access, ms-word, mailmerge

I wish to mail merge and email from an Access query and pre setup word doc. It appears to work fine, as a the merged data document appears along with a new merged document that I have (for now) save.  **BUT** what I really want it to do is send the actual email, rather than having to manually go to 'Finish & Merge" from MsWord. Simply it just doesn't actually send the email(s).

```
Function runMerge()


Dim StrFullDocPath As String
Dim oApp As Object

'Path to the word document
StrFullDocPath = "merge.docx" 'have removed the full path


'to save file name
outFileName = "Renewals_" & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy")

If Dir(StrFullDocPath) = "" Then
  MsgBox "Document not found"
Else
  'Create an instance of MS Word
  Set oApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  oApp.Visible = True

  'Open the Document
  oApp.Documents.Open FileName:=StrFullDocPath
End If

With oApp

  With .ActiveDocument.MailMerge
    .MainDocumentType = wdEMail
    .OpenDataSource _
        Name:="myDB.accdb", _
        LinkToSource:=True, _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        Connection:="QUERY qryCheckRenews", _
        SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [qryCheckRenews]"

    .Destination = wdSendToEmail
    .MailAddressFieldName = "EmailAddress"
    .MailFormat = wdMailFormatHTML
    .MailAsAttachment = False
    .MailSubject = "testing testing 1, 2, 3"
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    .Execute Pause:=False
     MsgBox "Mail Merge Complete ", vbOKOnly, "myDB"




  End With

  oApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="Renewal" & outFileName & ".docx"

  'oApp.Documents.Close savechanges:=False
  Set oApp = Nothing


End With


'Exit Sub
'ErrTrap:
 '   MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical

End Function
```

Any help gratefully received

Comment: Think will have to save the Word document then attach the saved document to email object.

Comment: Yes, I reverted to saving the document to later attach. Just can't work out why it doesn't email despite populating the email address, subject line etc. in the Finish and Merge menu dialog.

Comment: Did some testing and I do get the code to work. Email is sent. I had to use full path for the Word doc and the Access db.

Comment: When set to email type the document saved is just the template. When set to letter the merged document is saved. I tested with a data source limited to one record. Can't figure out how to make the output filename dynamic based on data and to save each individual merge.

Comment: Appreciate that. I was content to save the merged doc, which works in the above code. So the exact same code works (emails) for you? (clearly I use the full path too).

Comment: Yes, email is sent. Just did another test but with Outlook closed. When closed the email just sits in Outbox folder. If my virus protection definitions are out of date I get the Outlook warning popup. Expanded test to merge 3 addresses. Works as well. In no case do have to go to 'Finish & Merge' in Word.